# Home component JS to hide a button

Tags: javascript, home-page-component, button

So I wanted to hide the "save & new" button on case edit page layout. So I added a home component,  Narrow Left column and in the body click on show html.

```
< !--------Wait for the loading of the page--------->
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
function addLoadEvent(func) {
var oldonload = window.onload;
if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
} else {
    window.onload = function() {
        if (oldonload) {
            oldonload();
        }
        func();
    }
 }
}
addLoadEvent(function() {checkCasePage();}); 
</script> 
<!--------/Wait for the loading of the page---------> 

<!--------Case Button hide--------->
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
function checkCasePage() {
var currentURL = window.location.href;

if (currentURL.indexOf('/500') != -1) {
    if (document.getElementsByName("save_new")[0] != null)
        document.getElementsByName("save_new")[0].style.display = 'none';
    if (document.getElementsByName("save_new")[1] != null)
        document.getElementsByName("save_new")[1].style.display = 'none';
  }
 }
 </script> 
 <!--------/Case Button hide--------->
```

But It's not working. What am I missing here? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you are already on Summer 14, this won't work.

Comment: Thanks I remember now! So any workaround for hiding?

Comment: For an edit page, I'm mostly at a loss. View pages can still import scripts that can run, but edit pages are mostly locked down due to the update. I'm just glad I'm not in tech support anymore...

Comment: Thanks for the info. And yes I agree, I see many annoyed tech support ppl at the end of the day.

Comment: probably want to stop hiding these buttons. There may be a good reason why tech support gets annoyed around questions like these :-)

Comment: @sfdcfox Can you put that as an answer? THnx :)